# Node.js password reset

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, forgot-password

I have been working on password reset in Node.js and Express.js
So far, my code is working for emailing to the user for changing their password. Also, user can change their password and receives an email after changing the password.
Now, the problem is, I cannot show success message after submitting the password. After pressing the submit button, it redirect to reset.ejs page. 
Below is my code,

**reset.ejs**

```
<html>
<body style="margin-left:0px;">
    <div class="custom-header">
        <div class="custom-header-left">

        </div>
        <div class="custom-header-button">

        </div>
        <div class="custom-header-right">
            <a class="navbar-brand">
                <img alt="AGD" src="agdlogo.png" style="width:70%; margin-top:-22%;">
            </a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"> XXX &nbsp;</a>
            <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Top Bar-->

    <div id="fullpage">
        <div class="">
            <div class="col-md-12  custom-margin-top">
                <div class="panel panel-primary text-left">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Reset your Password</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="col-md-10 ">
                            <form id="resetpass" role="form" class="form">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="InputEmail">New Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" class="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
                                        <label for="InputEmail">Confirm Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="repass" class="repass" name="repass" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
                                        <!--    <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token">-->
                                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                            </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>


<script>
    var params = location.href;
    var paramsplit = params.split('/');
    //console.log(paramsplit);
    $("#resetpass").submit(function (e) {
        var resetData = {
            password: $("#password").val(),
            repass: $("#repass").val(),
            token: paramsplit[4]
        }

        console.log(resetData);

        // console.log(resetData);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '/reset/:token',
            data: JSON.stringify(resetData),
            success: function (data) {
                //console.log(data); // show response from the php script.
            }
        });

        // e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
</script>
<style CSS>
    @import url("https://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.min.css");
</style>
</html>
```

I have a mail.controller.js file for controlling the view and model

```
exports.resetpassword = function(req, res) {
  var data = req.body;

  async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
      User.findOne({
        resetPasswordToken: req.body.token,
        resetPasswordExpires: {
          $gt: Date.now()
        }
      }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
          res.render('tinypage/regnotify', {
            title: "Something is wrong",
            alerttype: "alert-danger",
            message: "Something wrong with your password change."
          });
        } else {
          user.password = req.body.password;
          user.resetPasswordToken = '';
          user.resetPasswordExpires = '';
          user.save(function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
          });
        }
      });
    },

    function(user, done) {
      var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
        service: 'Mailgun',
        auth: {
          user: 'sdfa',
          pass: 'afdafsa'
        }
      });

      var mailOptions = {
        to: user.email,
        from: 'agdtrack@s.com',
        subject: 'Your password has been changed',
        text: 'Hello,\n\n' +
          'This is a confirmation that the password for your account ' + req.body.token + ' has just been changed.\n'
      };

      smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          res.render('tinypage/regnotify', {
            title: "Wrong",
            alerttype: "alert-danger",
            message: "Something wrong"
          });
        } else {
          return res.render('tinypage/regnotify', {
            title: "Success",
            alerttype: "alert-success",
            message: "Success! Your password has been changed."
          });
          done(err);
        }
      });
    }
  ], function(err) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
};

exports.renderresetpage = function(req, res) {
  res.render('reset');
};
```

And my mail.route.js is :

```
app.route('/reset/:token').get(mail.renderresetpage);    
app.route('/reset/:token').post(mail.resetpassword);
```

All are working fine. Only does not show the success message after pressing submit button.

Your contribution would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a from will navigate to the form's action. You can add an 'onclick' to the button instead to keep you in the same page, and send the ajax request from it. So you can be able to handle the ajax success.